# Get hex string for a public address

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoin-cli

If I want to watch a public address, I need the hex string for that address, because the `importpubkey` command only takes a hex input. How can I convert a  base 58 address to a hex string using the bitcoin core?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I convert a SHA256 hash into a Bitcoin base58 private key?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/8247/how-can-i-convert-a-sha256-hash-into-a-bitcoin-base58-private-key)

Comment: I realize the above link does the conversion the other way; however it should help you get started.

Comment: @MaxVernon Uh, what??? This has nothing to do with private keys. Also, the conversion you cited is going the wrong way. That does not get me started. I want to know how to convert a base 58 pub key to a hex pub key USING THE CORE CLIENT.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot generate public key from a bitcoin address. From bitcoin address, all you can get is the hash160. Following [reference](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Technical_background_of_version_1_Bitcoin_addresses), this can be done through base58 decoding, going from Step 9 -> Step 8. So you get same output as from Step 4 along with checksum at the end.

Basically you have two alternatives:

- If you have the private key, generate the public key and use `importpubkey`
- Use `importaddress`

Answer (score 2):

You might want to use the `importaddress` RPC method (I'm not even aware of an `importpubkey` method).  The `importaddress` method accepts the base58 address string you have.  I recently asked a slightly-related question and ended up answering it myself here: [How to make ImportMulti function like ImportAddress for watch-only addresses placed into Accounts?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/62939/how-to-make-importmulti-function-like-importaddress-for-watch-only-addresses-pla/62987#62987)

Comment: When I do that, I get the error "couldn't connect to server".

Comment: Then you have a bigger problem!